# Cómo cambiar el formato de un botón en un formulario sin perder su funcionalidad

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Tengo un menú con varias opciones. Requiero procesar la Opcion3 como formulario para poder utilizar el **name** y el **value**.
Cómo puedo cambiar el formato del botón ***Opcion3*** para que se muestre como el texto de los botones ***Opcion1*** y ***Opcion2*** ?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav text-center">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="index.php?action=opcion1">Opcion1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="index.php?action=opcion2">Opcion2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <form action="index.php?action=opcion3" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="proceso">
        <input type="submit" value="Opcion3" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"></form>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Nota: Estoy utilizando **Bootstrap 4.5**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar CSS, borras la clase `btn-primery` y agregas una clase que defines. Por ejemplo `form-btn` comó aquí.

```
.form-btn {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  padding: 0;
}
.form-btn:hover {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

<input type="submit" value="Opcion3" class="btn btn-block form-btn" />
```

[Demo en Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bootstrap-forked-kb1ev?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: No necesitas una nueva clase y tampoco es transparente, solo debe usar la clase `.bg-light` en vez de `.btn-primary`

Comment: Claro,  buen punto.

Comment: Con sus aportes cambié __class="btn bg-dark btn-block text-white-50">__ y queda perfecto, pero habrá alguna forma de hacer que cambie de color como los elementos __ul__?

Comment: Si no es comó mi ejemplo en codesandbox, puedes inspeccionar los elementos en el `ul` para encontrar el color. Despues agregas CSS comò: `color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);`